# How to separate strings and then remove first part of seperated string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I would like to remove the first part of the separated string and the comma. However, I cannot simply use a query that removes the first three characters of a string as the character lengths vary (i.e. 10th).

Original data:

```
1st,4000;2nd,1200;3rd,600;4th,200;total_value,6000;
```

Code to separate strings:

```
SELECT 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,';',1)),';',-1) AS 1st,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX((SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrizeMoneyBreakDown,';',2)),';',-1) AS 2nd
FROM race2
```

Output of code (separated strings):

```
1st,4000
2nd,1200
```

Desired output of code:

```
4000
1200
```

Comment: I fail to see how this different in principal to your last question..given you can substring a substring (to quite a depth)

Comment: The answer is in here [Waiting for your visit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running MySQL 8+, then `REGEXP_SUBSTR` works here:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, '[0-9]+', 1, 2) AS first,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, '[0-9]+', 1, 4) AS second
FROM race2;
```

Comment: Thanks. What does 0-9 mean and 1,2

Comment: `[0-9]+` is a regex pattern matching a number.  The third parameter to `REGEXP_SUBSTR` means start searching at position 1, and the fourth parameter determines which match to return.